# Angular datatable with server side processing Ajax URL not well formed after the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

so I'm working with the MEAN stack (mongo, express, angular, node) and I'm trying to set a table with server-side processing, I managed to load the data correctly but when I search, change the page or another action the URL that is sent to the server is not the same as the first time. I have this controller for the table:

```
    .controller('ClientDatatableController', function($scope, $state, $filter, $compile, Client, popupService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder){
    var vm = this;

    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', '/api/clients/')
        .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('order', [0, 'desc'])
        .withOption('stateSave', true)
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withOption('createdRow', function(row) {
            // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
        })
        .withColumnFilter({
        aoColumns: [{
            type: 'number'
        }, {
            type: 'text',
            bRegex: true,
            bSmart: true
        }, {
            type: 'number'
        }, {
            type: 'text',
            bRegex: true,
            bSmart: true
        }, {
            type: 'text',
            bRegex: true,
            bSmart: true
        }]
    });

    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('numeroCliente').withOption('name','numeroCliente').withTitle('Número Cliente'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nome').withOption('name','nome').withTitle('Nome Cliente'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nif').withOption('name','nif').withTitle('NIF'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withOption('name','morada.concelho').withTitle('Concelho').renderWith(function(data, type, full){
            var morada = full.morada;
            if (morada.concelho) return morada.concelho;
            else return '';
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('').withOption('name','morada.localidade').withTitle('Localidade').renderWith(function(data, type, full){
            var morada = full.morada;
            if (morada.localidade) return morada.localidade;
            else return '';
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('_id')
                       .withTitle('')
                       .withOption('sortable', false)
                       .withClass('button-column')
                       .renderWith(function(data, type){
            var href = $state.href("viewClient", {id: data});

            return '<a class="btn btn-default" href=' + href + '><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a>';
        }),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('_id')
                       .withTitle('Apagar')
                       .withOption('autoWidth', false)
                       .withOption('width','10%')
                       .withOption('sortable', false)
                       .renderWith(function(data, type){
                           return '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  ng-click="deleteClient(\'' + data + '\')">Delete</a>'
                       })
    ];
```

I didn't find anyone with the same problem so far, the GET requests are the following:

```
GET /api/clients/?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=numeroCliente&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=numeroCliente&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=nome&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=nome&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=nif&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=nif&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=concelho&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=localidade&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=_id&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=_id&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=desc&start=0&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1508546310543 200 53.234 ms - 17452
GET /?draw=2&columns=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D&order=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&start=20&length=10&search=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&sRangeSeparator=~ 200 0.744 ms - 5926
```

As you can see the second request don't have /api/clients before, if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out that the problem was with the ColumnFilter plugin, so I changed the request type to POST and set the fnServerData function:

```
.withFnServerData((sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) => {
            $http.post('api/clients', {
                tableData: {
                    draw: aoData[0].value,
                    columns: aoData[1].value,
                    order: aoData[2].value,
                    start: aoData[3].value,
                    length: aoData[4].value,
                    search: aoData[5].value
                }                    
            }).then((data) => {                        
                fnCallback(data.data);                        
            });
        })
```